# node module pg client.end() doesn't close connections

Tags: node.js, postgresql

My application only makes select query every 3 seconds, when I run more than 1 pod with same app db connections get stuck, there are more than 20 active connections.

```
async test (text) {
    const client = new Client(main_db);
    await client.connect();
    try {
        const result = await client.query(text);
        return result.rows;
    } finally {
        await client.end();
    }
}
```

this is method witch using to make queries,[issue on git,there contributors told to use this method](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1695).

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is `main_db`?

Comment: it's the name of variable where db config is stored

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a connection pool, you cannot `end` connections. You will have to `release` the connections back to the pool to be re-used.

Refer https://node-postgres.com/api/pool#release-err-error-

If you are creating a new connection for every query fired, you shouldn't be having the above problem. You won't be having any problem on the client side (similar to the one mentioned in the question )if you are not closing the connections. The DB will be overloaded though.

Comment: I tried to create client/pool only 1 time for whole process,but there my problems began.Is there any solution how make query every +2 sec and don't overload db?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you using the pool or not? Please update the question asking specifically what your issue is.

Comment: I was using the pool,creating 1 time pool without closing   it,and got +20 active connections

Comment: Like I mentioned in the answer, you don't have to close the pool. You have to release the connections once used back to the pool. That will solve the issue. For your use case, you could start with creating/opening a connection and closing the connection for every query fired.

Comment: `release()` dosn't help,again sucked connections

Comment: Can you post the complete code in the question with the pool configuration,query and connection.release code?

Comment: I think problem is that db isn't local,the transport layout takes more than 3-4 sec,and bcs its reaped every 3 sec its get sucked,thank you